# Разбить содержимое файлов на предложения и затем на слова

Tags: java, token

Подскажите пожалуйста, как считать из директории (папки) все файлы (они в формате txt) и разбить их содержимое на слова.
Пыталась написать:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Fil {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  File files = new File("C://Instructions");
  List < String > textFiles = new ArrayList < String > ();
  for (File file: files.listFiles()) {
   try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String str = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: И чем завершилась ваша попытка? Какие трудности или сообщения об ошибке? Отформатируйте код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы прочитать все файлы txt из папки попробуйте это:

```
File myfolder = new File("/путь к папке");
File[] listOfFiles = myfolder.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  File file = listOfFiles[i];
  if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    /* обработка */
  } 
}
```

А разбить на слова совсем просто: Перебираете посимвольно весь текст файла. Если следующий символ пробел или знак пунктуации, то их пропускаем и заносим предыдущий блок символов как новый элемент массива.
Или воспользоваться:

```
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
```

А потом "почистить" элементы массива от знаков пунктуации.

Comment: Спасибо, скажите пожалуйста как быть с FileUtils, выдает ошибку. Вписывала `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.` (пишет org. не существует). В org.apache есть lang, logging, но io.FileUtils нет.

Comment: FileUtils - класс из пакета apache org.apache.commons.io, поэтому вам нужно скачать org.apache.commons.io.jar, а затем, встроить этот файл. У меня стоит Eclipse, там это делается так: открываете project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add External Jars. Так вы сможете добавить jar. Загрузить можно [отсюда](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все получилось)